# Disable a Form Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a formpanel, i need to disable it when a condition is met.

```
if (conditionIsMet){

        var theFormPanel= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#winId> #theFormPanel')[0];


}
```

but how can i disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (conditionIsMet){
  var theFormPanel= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#winId> #theFormPanel')[0].disable();
}
```

Why do you use ComponentQuery query here? Can't you get formpanel by id? `Ext.getCmp('formPanelId').disable();`